# Newton method exchanging row

Tags: newton-raphson

suppose to have a function $F(x,y,z) = [ f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z)]$  and that $f_1$ depend only by x, $f_2$ depends only by y and $f_3$ depends only by z.
Now if I apply newton method I can write  $[d_x,d_y,d_z] = -J^{-1}(x,y,z)*F(x,y,z)$.

The question is if I exchange the rows of $F$ for example in this way $F_{new}(x,y,z) = [ f_2(x,y,z),f_1(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z)]$ it seems I can write in the same way this $[d_x,d_y,d_z] = -J^{-1}(x,y,z)*F_{new}(x,y,z)$ , but intuitively I expect something like this $[d_y,d_x,d_z] = -J^{-1}(x,y,z)*F_{new}(x,y,z)$.

Can you please explain me why the inversion of rows doesn't affect the steps retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the permutation that swaps these rows is also applied to the Jacobian. Let this permutation be $P$, then we have
$$
F_{new} = PF\implies J_{new} = PJ.
$$
The Newton step $s_{new}$ is then
$$
s_{new} = -J_{new}^{-1}F_{new}(x_k) = -J^{-1}P^{-1}PF = -J^{-1}F(x_k) = s
$$